# Inkscape: How can I create a circular plane with excited circles of different angle?

Tags: inkscape, 3d

I have only once used Inkscape so far and need to make a graphic for my thesis work for an illustration of a geometrical principle. Imagine our solar system as a circular plane. The plane is the average of all the planets that circle around it. Now each individual planet is inclined towards this average(!) plane.

[image]

I would like to draw a plane that shows this inclination of each planet. Something like this (not necessarily with scaling):

[image]

How can I do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems more a work for [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) (see [here](https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/blob/master/demo/orbits.dem) and [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m309-01a/orbits.pdf) for example - and [her](https://github.com/davidn/planet) for some data). Or for [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). You can export the data in SVG too.

Comment: Well, it's just the geometric principle that I want to show. I guess I could draw the inclined circles in Inkscape and rotate them somehow (the orbits are not only angles but their orbit-maxima are also rotated towards each other) or make them appear rotated from the beginning. But it does look ugly I think to only draw circles. Imagine a belt like the asteroid belt between Mars and Jupiter - this is not a line but a circular plane in itself. Or the Kuiper belt behind Neptune. For such belts a 3d plane is much more beautiful - assuming that all objects on the same orbit have same inclination.

Comment: Mmm... something like the images near the end of this [page](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/ast121/lectures/lec24.html)?

Comment: Either I misunderstood what you want to do or you are striving to create an unreadable diagram.

Comment: Or perhaps you intend an ellipse (representing the plane) translated following a path (the orbit), like [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-PatternAlongPath.html)? Please, be a little more specific.